# Unable to style the color of bullets in a list

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the colour of the list points but it's not working?

```
<div class="mobile-menu" id="mobile-menu">
        <div id="mobile-menu-links">
            <h4>General:</h4>
            <ul class="mobile-menu-links">
                <li><a href="">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="">The boring rules!</a></li>
                <li><a href="">The rankings</a></li>
            </ul>

.mobile-menu #mobile-menu-links ul{
                list-style-type: none;
                margin:0;
                padding-left:3%;
            }

            .mobile-menu #mobile-menu-links ul li{
                padding-bottom:2px;
                border-bottom:1px solid #bababa;
            }
```

If I add `color:red` in either of the two CSS declarations, it doesn't change the colour.

Please note that the HTML is closed in my document, I just copied the first part for you to see.

Thanks.

Comment: you may be looking for this... http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/ytH5P/

Comment: I want to change the colour of the text, not the bullet.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XVwaf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple ways to do it...

1. idea behind coloring the bullets

   ```
   ul { list-style: none; }

   li:before { content:"\2022 \00A0"; color: red; }
   ```

   [jsfiddle](http://zekefranco.me/demos/bullets/)
2. [another link](http://jsfiddle.net/raw9a/)

as per comment, I am able to see color change [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RjuQh/)

Comment: I think the question has been misundestood! I want to change the colour of the text!

Comment: Memory block, didn't consider it was a link. Don't usually use unordered lists for links so confused myself there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please add extra below CSS stuff

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;} 
a:visited {color:#00FF00;}
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}  
a:active {color:#0000FF;}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XVwaf/)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this http://jsfiddle.net/Dnxmm/. [ul] must be front.

```
ul.mobile-menu-links{
            margin:0;
            padding-left:3%;
            color:red;
        }

 ul.mobile-menu-links li{
            padding-bottom:2px;
            border-bottom:1px solid #bababa;
            color:red;
        }
```